# Implementing a Boolean function using NOR gates with maximum 4 ports

Tags: logic-gates, boolean-algebra

I need to implement a Boolean function using NOR gates only. The minimized function written as PoS is:

**f(a, b, c, d) = (a+b)(a+c+d)(b+c+d')(a+c'+d')(a'+c'+d)**

I used double negation and DeMorgan's laws to make the following (unfinished) circuit in the Hades simulator:
[image]

Now, the problem is that Hades has NOR gates that have a maximum of 4 ports, and I have 5 separate sums I need to input in the NOR gate. Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cascade them. Send two of the inputs into a NOR gate and then invert the result to send it into the last one.